# MySQL server erroring

Tags: mysql

I've a MySQL server which I'm writing to about every 10 minutes.  It seems to work fine then when I go back to it a few hours later it has crashed.

From `error.log` I have

```
2017-01-17T13:47:35.315801Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
2017-01-17T13:47:35.315905Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)
2017-01-17T13:47:35.495187Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp serv$
2017-01-17T13:47:35.497022Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) starting as process 18742 ...
2017-01-17T13:47:35.505459Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2017-01-17T13:47:35.505530Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-01-17T13:47:35.505541Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2017-01-17T13:47:35.505549Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2017-01-17T13:47:35.505558Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2017-01-17T13:47:35.505566Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2017-01-17T13:47:35.506116Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2017-01-17T13:47:35.506338Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-01-17T13:47:35.508891Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2017-01-17T13:47:35.508951Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: mmap(137428992 bytes) failed; errno 12
2017-01-17T13:47:35.508973Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2017-01-17T13:47:35.508983Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2017-01-17T13:47:35.508994Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2017-01-17T13:47:35.509002Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2017-01-17T13:47:35.509011Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2017-01-17T13:47:35.509017Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2017-01-17T13:47:35.509026Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2017-01-17T13:47:35.509098Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2017-01-17T13:47:35.509118Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2017-01-17T13:47:35.509507Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

This is a database I'm running from Python/Django, not that I think that should make any difference.  I do not know what is going wrong but if I reboot the server it starts up and works fine.  Could you help please.

Comment: `Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool`. It wants 128 megabytes, do you have that much free? You can increase your swap size (which is rather pointless, MySQL will be snail-slow). You can lower the buffer pool, which, again - makes MySQL slow. Or, you can ensure you have 128 megs free for MySQL. If you want your database to perform somewhat optimal, it has to allocate some RAM to hold its working data set there (because reading from RAM >>>>> reading from HDD).

Comment: I agree with @Mjh, looks like you've run out of memory.

Comment: I'm running it on a $10pm Digital Ocean droplet which is meant to have 1GB  / 1CPU; 30 GB SSD and 2 TB transfer.  That sounds like enough to me but if not would the memory issue be trying to save to big a record at 1 time?

Comment: If the server has 1GB of RAM, that doesn't mean it has enough *free* RAM. MySQL daemon tried to allocate 128MB and failed, that means you don't have 128MB free. Error that you posted states that MySQL failed initializing InnoDB storage engine and that it's exiting. What I find odd is that you're able to use MySQL and then it dies. Are you sure you don't have multiple MySQL's installed?

Comment: I only delibrately installed 1.  How would I check?

Comment: To be honest, the only thing I have running is MySQL and then I'm calling a Python cron job every 10 minutes which is scraping data off a webpage and saving it to the database.  Then once a day I go into the website I've set up to front this and download the data.

Comment: Since you're constrained with memory, how about you try to set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to a lower value, for example 64MB? There's too many questions that we might ask, but it looks like your Python process eats up a lot of memory which leaves insufficient amount for MySQL. We don't know *how* you're dealing with insertion in Python, whether you're sending big chunks of data or if you're using prepared statements to be easy on your db server. But, if stability is what you're after and not performance, then you might lower the mentioned variable and see how it goes from there.

Comment: I've been monitoring the server memory usage with `top` (I don't know if that makes sense) and I seem to be getting multiple copies of Firefox running, which is taking the memory, so I'm not closing it down correctly in my python script.  I think this is the issue but I cannot understand why Firefox isn't closing properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I increased the size of the server and it has been working fine.  I'll live with it